# Code Keeps Trying To Send Email After Blocked Email Error

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am trying to get code that sends email to fail decently when a blocked email is added as the 'To' address.  The problem I am having is that the SmtpClient keeps trying to send the email.  I would like the code to exit after the exception.  Any ideas on what is going on here?  How to get around this issue?

example email:  bademail@fakegmail.com

Error
Additional information: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Related code

```
    public void Send(string body)
    {
        try
        {
            string configSubject = "emailSubject";
            var emailSubject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configSubject];
            var emailFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailFrom"];
            var emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailTo"];
            var emails = emailTo.Split(',');

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.Subject = emailSubject;
            message.Body = body;
            message.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            foreach (string email in emails)
            {
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
            }
            var client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch {
            throw;//error occurs on send because of the bad email 
                  //and then a loop starts with this line of code 
                  //getting hit over and over and ovar. 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code, if you can, that calls your `Send()` method.

Comment: This code would exit upon exception. However, the code that calls your `Send()` method may be re-calling this.

Comment: There is no mechanism in this code to re-try a failed attempt.  The problem is very likely somewhere else.  (Also note that the try/catch here is entirely superfluous.  Hopefully your actual code isn't like that?)

Comment: Also, you should get rid of the try/catch block (it does nothing), and you should put your `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` into `using` blocks.